# Load HTML Table in PUG template based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

tl;dr: To give a clear and concise idea of what I want, when a user selects a state from the dropdown selector list, I only want the table to display the locations relevant to that state. On page load users will view the entire table. Then I want to be able to filter the view based on the dropdown selection. I hope this makes sense. I have a function written in jquery but it's not doing exactly what I expected

I've got a **list** of **states** in a dropdown list like so:

```
select#states(form='addProperty', name='propertyType') 
      option(value='0') -- Select A State --
      option(value='AL') Alabama
      option(value='AK') Alaska
      option(value='AZ') Arizona
      option(value='AR') Arkansas 
      option(value='CA') California
      option(value='CO') Colorado
      option(value='CT') Connecticut
      option(value='DE') Delaware
      option(value='FL') Florida
```

I've also got a table that looks like this:
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaE6K.jpg)

I wrote this **table** in a **pug** template like so:

```
table.table
    tr 
        th State
        th Description 
        th SMS ID Name
            for item in lists
                tr
                    td.state #{item.state}
                    td #{item.name}
                    td #{item.location}
```

I've got this **jquery** function:

```
$("#states").on("change",
    function(){
        var a = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        console.log(a);
        $("table tr td").each(
            function(){
                if($(this).html() != a){
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).show();
                }
        });
});
```

This function is hiding everything except for the 'State' column. For example:

[function behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YqbJ.jpg)

I know my function is coded to hide everything that doesn't have a .html value matching my selection, but I can't figure out how to hide entire rows that don't match my selection

I'm a beginner so please take it easy on me :)

Comment: If I can improve my question please let me know, I'm new to stack overflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem after basically using this post to as rubber duck debugging.

For anyone that's curious, here is my working solution.

```
table.table
    th State
    th Description 
    th SMS ID Name
        for item in lists
            tr(class=item.state)
                td.state #{item.state}
                td.name #{item.name}
                td.loc #{item.location}
                script.
                    var dropdown = document.getElementById("states");
                    dropdown.onchange = function({{console.log(dropdown.value);}};
                        $("#states").on("change",
                        function(){
                          var option = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                          $("tr").each(
                            function(){
                              if($(this).hasClass(option)){
                                console.log(this);
                                $(this).show();
                              }
                              else{
                                $(this).hide();
                              }
                            });
                        });
```

The solution was pretty simple in the end. I had to assign a class dynamically to each row. I did this with `tr(class=item.state)`. From there I iterated each `tr`, and checked for a class that matched my selection in the drop down list.

My post was viewed over 47 times and got no answer, so hopefully this post can help someone.